# Get variable other class java Android

Tags: java, android, html, variables

I'm trying to get textview to display a number, but it will not.

My activity code:

```
package com.example.gotteron;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Classement extends Activity{

    TextView textview;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.classement);
        GetCode getCode = new GetCode();
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {
            textview.setText(getCode.test());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Class to get HTMl:

```
//Package
package com.example.gotteron;

//Import
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class GetCode{

    public String test() throws Exception{

        //Recupérer le code HTML de la page
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.nationalleague.ch/NL/fr/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String s1 = "";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            s1 = s1 + inputLine;
        in.close();

        int Berne = s1.indexOf(">SC Bern</td>");
        String s3 = String.valueOf(Berne); 
        return s3;
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/firstPosition" />

</LinearLayout>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gotteron"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gotteron.Principal"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Classement" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Calendrier" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Live" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the code but there's still a problem. When I run the Application the textview displays his default message. During this time, the logcat displays a lot of messages:
http://pastebin.com/244grjYt
and at the end the app crashes

Comment: On Which Emulator version, you are running the above code?

Comment: Android 4.2 - API Level 17

Comment: You can reach it by a hack ;) if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
         {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
          }

Comment: My bad, fixed it, see my answer + comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, this is what the other answers are about. Since you haven't check anything as answer, maybe this will help.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    TextView textview;
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.classement);
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        new NetworkOperation().execute();
    }

    private class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL oracle = new URL("http://www.nationalleague.ch/NL/fr/");
                URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                String s1 = "";
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    s1 = s1 + inputLine;
                in.close();
                int Berne = s1.indexOf(">SC Bern</td>");
                String s3 = String.valueOf(Berne); 
                return s3;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }      

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textview.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1965878 My bad. Need to set `textview`: `findViewById(R.id.textview);` should be `textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);`

Comment: Thank's it works but I have to wait 1min30 before the textview displays. I'm going to test on my phone. Thank's for the time you spent !

Comment: i tested and on the phone it loads only for 10 seconds. Thanks everibody !

Comment: @user1965878 Good to know that it works. Since we solved your problem, please check an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a network connection (HTTP connection) i the ui thread, try to move the call to `getCode.test()` into another thread or better into an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)..

Comment: I am going to see what's "AsyncTask" and I'll tell you again if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are facing `NetworkOnMainThread` Exception which is quite common on Emulators that are running on API level 11 and more when you are writing Network Related code in UI Thread. You change your code into `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask` and run it.

In  your case as you are throwing Exception in test() it will not crash your app because Exceptions are caught by Exception.

Example Code:

```
class FetchResultTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{
protected String doInBackground()
{
  //your network related code.
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
  super.onPostExecute(result);
   //set the result to TextView here.
}
}
```

Comment: I am going to see what's "AsyncTask" and I'll tell you again if it works. Thanks

Comment: To use findViewById(), my class musts extends Activity. Are you sure I have to put doInBackground() & onPostExecute in the same class ?

Comment: you have declared textView as global variable. So you can write the above asynctask inside your Activity Class and can use the textView inside onPostExecute().

Comment: I'm not sure to understand everything... Must I create a new class ?

Comment: @user1965878 follow the answer given by Christian